# Neo4JClient: Parameter in Match() clause

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to create a generic repository. For some reason, having a parameter in the Match() clause does not seems to work. Anyone know what the problem might be? My code looks like this (I'm a C#/.net Developer):

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetNodCollectionByLabel<T>(string nodLabel)
{
    IEnumerable<T> entityList = new List<T>();

    entityList = _graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(entity:{nodLabel})")
        .WithParam("nodLabel", nodLabel)
        .Return(entity => entity.As<T>())
        .Results;

    return entityList.ToArray();
}
```

The exception is:

SyntaxException: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a label name (line 1, column 15 (offset: 14)) "MATCH (entity:{nodLabel})" ^

Comment: Does `nodLabel` relate to `T` in any way?

Answer (score 1):

.withParam() is for the Cypher parameters as they meant, not for the labels.

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html

You cannot use parameters for labels.

One approach for you is to use String.Format();

```
private IList<string> GetAllLabels()
{
     return _graphClient.Cypher
                        .Match("(n)")
                        .Return<List<string>>("DISTINCT labels(n)")
                        .Results;
}

private bool isValidNode(string name)
{
    return GetAllLabels().Contains(name.Trim());
}

private IEnumerable<T> GetNodCollectionByLabel<T>(string nodLabel)
{
    IEnumerable<T> entityList = new List<T>();

    if (!isValidNodeLabel(nodLabel))
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }

    var statement = String.Format("(entity:{0})", nodLabel);

    entityList = _graphClient.Cypher
                             .Match(statement)
                             .Return(entity => entity.As<T>())
                             .Results;

    return entityList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Oh, alright! That explains everything. I have thought about using string.Format(), but that's a dangerous approach if we are getting data from the end-user.

Comment: @JL-ConcepT I extended my example. You right about dangerous approach and I did some basic validation. I think now you have idea how to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you once again! I modified your changes slightly to suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetNodCollectionByLabel<T>(string nodLabel)
{
    IEnumerable<T> entityList = new List<T>();

    entityList = _graphClient.Cypher
        .Match("(entity:nodLabel)")
        .WithParam("nodLabel", nodLabel)
        .Return(entity => entity.As<T>())
        .Results;

    return entityList.ToArray();
}
```

If you really have a param named "nodLabel" it will return some data.

The problem here was that you were looking for a node like this:

`MATCH (entity:{nodLabel}) ...`

but you have to specify the node label if you are using `:`, so you got a parsing error, because you did not specified a label for the node you were matching.

Comment: Thank you your reply! 

However, invoking the method with your changes just returns a empty array. According to the documentation, the parameter syntax should look like this: {someValue}. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: My example returns an empty array because you don't have a nodeLabel parameter, remove ` .WithParam("nodLabel", nodLabel)` line and you'll get something (only if you have some nodes in your database using `nodLabel` as label)